# Remove equal item from java list

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of items, where each item is a simple class containing 2 public strings.
I have an equals method that simply makes use of the equalsIgnoreCase methot of String for both strings.

```
public class data
{
    public String a;
    public String b;

    public boolean equals(data d)
    {
        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(d.a) && b.equalsIgnoreCase(d.b))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to remove an element even if it's not the same instance of the one in the list but equal to it.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
public void remove(data dataToRemove)
{
    for(data i : _list)
    {
        if(i.equals(dataToRemove))
        {
            _list.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: depending on how important order is to your collection you could consider using a Map, like a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). This way you can just look up your object by key. It's better than using a loop, but not always necessary.

Comment: A List is not the best container for this exercise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A few comments:

- Your `equals` method **does not** override the `equals` method of `Object` (argument should be of `Object` type, not `data` type).
- You should improve your `equals` method to account for nulls etc.
- And finally, you should override `hashcode()` too when you override `equals()` - if not you might encounter some weird behaviors when using Sets or Maps for example.

If you properly override the `equals` method, you can then just use the `remove` method.
See below the auto generated `equals` and `hashcode` generated by Netbeans, amended to use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>();
    list.add(new Data("a", "b"));
    list.add(new Data("a", "c"));
    System.out.println(list.size()); //2
    list.remove(new Data("A", "b"));
    System.out.println(list.size()); //1
}

public static class Data {

    public String a;
    public String b;

    public Data(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final Data other = (Data) obj;
        boolean sameA = (this.a == other.a) || (this.a != null && this.a.equalsIgnoreCase(other.a));
        if (!sameA) return false;
        boolean sameB = (this.b == other.b) || (this.b != null && this.b.equalsIgnoreCase(other.b));
        if (!sameB) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.a == null ? 0 :this.a.toUpperCase().hashCode());
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.b == null ? 0 : this.b.toUpperCase().hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and complete answer! It's very helpful.

Comment: This is the appropriate approach (to override equals, as well as hashCode, which should always be overridden alongside equals), but the autogenerated equals above does not match the equals that he used (something that he can reimplement).

Comment: @pickypg I have amended accordingly

Comment: @assylias: It's not just good practice to override `hashCode()` if you override `equals()`, it's required by the contract of those methods. While non-hash-based collections like `List` may behave correctly even if `hashCode()` isn't overridden properly, other data structures won't.

Answer (score 1):

The clearest way is to just call the [Remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) method of the list without any loops and pass in your object the parameter. It uses the equals method that you defined on the object to find and remove it if it exists in the list.

```
_list.remove(data);
```

You also don't have to specify the hashcode method, but you should get in the habit of always creating one when you override the equals method in case you use it in a collection like a Set or a Map.

Comment: His equals method does not override Object.equals so remove will not work as he expects.

Comment: What a good catch! The @Override annotation proves it's use once again.